# Auto detect Otp in Expo(react-native) app

Tags: react-native, expo

I am trying to implement auto detect Otp functionality in my react-native expo app and i am using the "react-native-otp-verify" library for it but getting the linking error.

Code

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from "react-native"
import { useOtpVerify } from "react-native-otp-verify"
import Button from "../component/Button"
import Input from "../component/Input"
import { setLoggedInResponse, useStore } from "../Store/Store"

const Otp = ({ moveToNextScreen }) => {
    const [otp, setOtp] = useState(undefined)
    const [otpText, setOtpText] = useState('')
    const [err, setError] = useState(undefined)
    const { mobile } = useStore()
    const { otp: OtpCode } = useOtpVerify({ numberOfDigits: 6 })
    const verifyOtp = ({ otp }) => {
        fetch("https://web.com/api/v1/verify_otp", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                Accept: 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                mobile,
                otp
            })
        }).then((res) => res.json())
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res)
                if (res.status.result) {
                    moveToNextScreen()
                    setLoggedInResponse(res.data)
                }
                else setError(res.status.message)
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
                setError(err)
            })
            .finally(() => {
                setOtp('')
            })
    }

    const handleClick = () => {
        setError(undefined)
        setOtp(otpText)
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        if (otp)
            verifyOtp({ otp })
        else if (OtpCode)
            verifyOtp({ otp: OtpCode })
    }, [otp, OtpCode])
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Input autoFocus={true} autoComplete="sms-otp" textContentType="oneTimeCode" value={otpText} onChange={setOtpText} style={{ textAlign: "center" }} placeholder={"Enter Otp"} />
            <Button title="Submit" onClick={handleClick} />
            {err && <Text style={styles.error}>{JSON.stringify(err)}</Text>}
        </View>
    )
}

export default Otp
```

Error

ERROR  Error: The package 'react-native-otp-verify' doesn't seem to be linked. Make sure:

- You rebuilt the app after installing the package
- You are not using Expo managed workflow
  , js engine: hermes
  ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:

- Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
- A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called., js engine: hermes

Since we can not manually link in expo app, is there any way to solve this issue ?